# Manage Exotaxonomy

Tags: science-based, biology, xenobiology, genetic-engineering, taxonomy

My story is **set on a huge ring megastructure ([Banks'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Culture#Orbitals) [Orbital](https://www.orionsarm.com/eg-article/4845ef5c4ca7c))**, with properties (E.g. axial tilt, diameter, rotation) that allow it to **have an Earth-like atmosphere**.

---

The biosphere is **similar to the Earth's**.

Life is Organic (Based on Carbon), and the data transfer method is DNA.
**All Organisms were generated from a [transapient](https://www.orionsarm.com/eg-topic/45c53f5eca9d9) entity**, starting with a common [computronium](https://www.orionsarm.com/eg-article/4637faafa6437)/body diagram (So as to simulate a Universal Ancestor) and adding various properties (So as to create several taxons IMMEDIATELY).

So the transapient species has ONLY BEGUN the "chain reaction", creating ONLY THE FIRST ORGANISMS, which then EVOLVED NATURALLY.

---

### QUESTION:

How can I **create and categorize species in a [taxonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomy) DIFFERENT from that used by Human on Earth** (E.g. an Organism similar in external morphology and appearance to a Plant-Tree, but with a different anatomy, or more general a taxon similar to Plant)?

IMPORTANT: I'd like an answer with both possibilities: It's been a short (Centuries)/long (Milions of year) time since artificial [speciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speciation).

Comment: How much time has passed since the creation of your starting species? Natural selection of variations will work in this setting, so there may be two layers of speciation to consider.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the question. What do you mean when you ask *how* you, the author, the one true omnipotent god in the fictional world, can create stuff in that world? Obviously, you speak it into existence. *"And God said, let the earth bring forth grass, the herb yielding seed, and the fruit tree yielding fruit after his kind, whose seed is in itself, upon the earth: and it was so. And the earth brought forth grass, and herb yielding seed after his kind, and the tree yielding fruit, whose seed was in itself, after his kind: and God saw that it was good."* (Genesis 1:11-12.)

Comment: P.S. A taxon is a set of organisms which is perceived by taxonomists to be distingushable from other such sets of organisms. Taxa are artificial creations, which may or may not correspond to natural groups of organisms, such as species or clades. (Fun fact: the English word *taxon* with its plural *taxa* look as if they are of Greek origin; but they are not. The word is fake Greek, and was invented by Adolf Meyer-Abich in 1926, exactly with the purpose of denoting "those things to which taxonomists apply names, whether they are real natural groups or not".)

Comment: VTC: Opinion-based, too story-based, might not even be a worldbuilding question from the perspective of the world (sounds more like you want us to help you categorize your creations?) Worse, we don't answer questions of the form "what's the best name for X?", which this is, because names are either an aesthetic (not a rule of the world) or based too much on the story (the evolution of language and science on the world).

Comment: I can't help but feel that you couldn't do this unless you designed your alien races first. When you do that, you'd probably come up with your own taxonomy. You might be able to clearly categorize them by the environment they lived in, but that wouldn't be a taxonomy.

Comment: Agree with most of what AlexP says. Taxonomy has been done forever, see e.g. its Wikipedia article; Aristotle and Linnaeus are the two most famous taxonomists, and the whole business was pretty empirical (or if you're cynical, arbitrary) until DNA sequencing became common. Just look for patterns in your organisms and make up some taxa that make them (look) more organised. Aristotle's system in particular might be a fun starting point for a system that aci-fi audiences that aren't biologists will suspend disbelief for.

Comment: Please don't link to Orion's arm, in place of explaining things yourself. It does not clear things up as much as you might suspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cladistics and phylogeny

[image]

This is how modern biological handles classification, relationships are established based on shared characteristics (genetic and/or morphological) and thus shared evolutionary history. You may be thinking of an outdated form of classification, Linnaean taxonomy (Class mammalia, kingdom animalia, ect.), this was based on essentially arbitrary ranking of characteristics. This would be A useless on another planet and B basically useless in modern biology. You have to use characteristics to organize organism relationships, but modern biology does not try to rank groups instead they are just classified based on more related vs less related. Characteristics are used to reconstruct presumed shared ancestor. These have been made for fictional organisms before.

If you want to understand cladistics there is a great website. https://evolution.berkeley.edu/phylogenetic-systematics/reconstructing-trees-cladistics/

And a useful video for getting started.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPcNfQfjjiw&t=28s

And a great website for helping you create an evolutionary history for your fictional organisms. https://kjworldsong.wordpress.com/2018/12/14/fictional-phylogeny-part-1-how-to-create-an-alien-ecosystem/

Comment: Evolution is not really a thing on this scenario. Linnaean or even Aristotelian style taxonomy with their somewhat arbitrary categories will be necessary.

Comment: @SeanOConnor if they are reproducing evolution is happening, also cladistics will work just fine with multiple origins.

Comment: @SeanOConnor The transapient species has only begun the "chain reaction", creating ONLY THE FIRST ORGANISMS, which then EVOLVED NATURALLY. My question was simply how do I categorize new organisms, and John's Cladistics is the answer.